# Apache Module mod_proxy_balancer

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-balancer

We are using apache version 2.2.23 in our environment.We have configured apache in such a way that it should load balance between two applications servers for the same home page.

BalancerMember abc:8101
 BalancerMember abc:8102 status=+H

we need to know how the apache web server is detecting that the server 8101 is down???
is it a ping or Telnet or something other then this.

Answer (score 2):

Apache HTTPd does not have out of band healthcheck for BalancerMember. It will detect that a given server is down when a proxyfied request to this server fails.

The documentation can be found here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html